# Criar uma backup de banco de dados que esta no azure

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-azure

Gostaria de fazer um backup de uma banco de dados que esta no Azure.
Tentei fazer o backup pelo Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, mas não aparece a opção de fazer backup.

Tentei fazer o backup pelo portal do Azure, mas não tem a opção.

Comment: Vc está usando Azure SQL Database? Ou é uma VM sua com SQLServer instalado?

Answer (score 1):

Os backups da PaaS Azure SQL Database é automatico. Não é necessário nenhuma configuração adicional para isso.

Ele é realizado a cada 5 a 10 minutos. Ele gera backups [completos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms186289.aspx), [diferenciais](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms175526.aspx) e de [log de transações](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms191429.aspx).

Esse backups podem ser recuperados da seguinte maneira:

- Restaurar um banco de dados para um ponto no tempo dentro do período de retenção. Essa operação criará um novo banco de dados no mesmo servidor do banco de dados original.
- Restaure um banco de dados excluído para a hora em que ele foi excluído ou em qualquer momento dentro do período de retenção. O banco de dados excluído pode ser restaurado apenas no mesmo servidor em que o banco de dados original foi criado.
- Restaure um banco de dados para outra região geográfica. Isso permite a recuperação de um desastre geográfico quando você não consegue acessar o servidor nem o banco de dados. Ele cria um novo banco de dados em qualquer servidor existente do mundo.
- Restaure um banco de dados de um backup específico armazenado no cofre dos Serviços de Recuperação do Azure. Isso permite restaurar uma versão antiga do banco de dados para atender a uma solicitação de conformidade ou para executar uma versão antiga do aplicativo. Consulte [Retenção de longo prazo](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/sql-database/sql-database-long-term-retention).
- Para executar uma restauração, consulte [Restaurar um banco de dados de backups](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/sql-database/sql-database-recovery-using-backups).

Saiba mais sobre [backup do Azure SQL Database](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automated-backups#a-namewhat-is-a-sql-database-backupao-que-%C3%A9-um-backup-de-banco-de-dados-sql).